# Internet Explorer Not Loading Glyph Icons / Open Sans on Initial Render in HTTPS

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, glyphicons

I have the following issue. I have a AngularJs/Bootstrap application, which displays some glyph-icons on the Login page as well as in the security context of the wrapped Spring 4 application.

On the login page, neither Open Sans font nor Glyph-Icons will load in Internet Explorer 10 or 11 (maybe also below, haven't tested). All other browsers work fine. The weird part is that, once I log into the server side webapp (Spring 4), both the font as well as the icons start showing. Even if I log back out they are now visible on the Login page (until I kill the browser and load the page again).

The whole things seems to work fine locally, in HTTP, but not in QA, which is in HTTPS.

Here the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/libs/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/libs/font-awesome.min.css"/>

@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(fonts/opensans/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2'), url(fonts/opensans/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
```

}

The fonts are under:
webapp/assets/fonts/opensans

Furthermore I dont get any 404s on the elements looking into the inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I must have changes the bootstrap.min.css and the font-awesome.min.css when I started with the project for some reason.

After re-downloading those sources through bower, the problem went away.

When comparing the old and the new files, I see that I must have removed the .ttf and .eot imports of the fonts.

For people facing similar issues, make sure to import all needed formats (for all browsers), this includes but may not be limited to: .woff, .woff2, .eot, .ttf. Also, don't make custom changes to the .min files :P